# Как настроить SWAGGER в VERT.X REST project

Tags: java, maven, rest, swagger, vert.x

У меня есть MAVEN + JAVA + VERT.X REST API проект. Мне надо настроить SWAGGER-UI в проект.

1. Когда делаеться BUILD проекта нужно чтобы SWAGGER YAML file генерировался на основе существующих Routes/Paths/Public API проекта
2. Когда делаеться RUN проекта нужно чтобы SWAGGER-UI запустился на localhost:8080/swagger и содержал API проекта.

**MAVEN**

```
 <plugin>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-codegen-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <inputSpec>
                       ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/api.yaml
                    </inputSpec>
                    <language>java</language>
                    <configOptions>
                       <sourceFolder>src/gen/java/main</sourceFolder>
                    </configOptions>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
 </plugin>
```

**VERT.X**

```
public void start(Future<Void> future) {
        final Router router = Router.router(vertx);

        router.route("/").handler(routingContext -> {
            HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
            response.putHeader("content-type", "text/html").end("<h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>");
        });

        vertx.createHttpServer().requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8080, result -> {
            if (result.succeeded()) {
                future.complete();
            } else {
                future.fail(result.cause());
            }
        });
}
```

**PROJECT**

- root

  - src

    - main

      - java

        - com

          - app

            - Main.java
      - resources

        - api.yaml
- pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Swagger/OpenAPI это спецификация вашего сервиса. Первичность описания более верный подход к построению сервиса, иначе говоря, вы пишите то что хотите в Swagger/OpenAPI и затем генерируете сервис по нему. И уже сгенерированный сервис дополняете своей имплементацией. А раз у вас есть первично swagger file to UI это простой статичный web клиент от Swagger UI.
В Vertx есть поддержка только OpenAPI3RouterFactory так как он свободный формат.